# What/How + the verb "describe"

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, questions

**Describe** is pretty common with **how**, for example: How do you describe yourself?

My question is: Can I use **what** with the verb **describe**, for example: What do you describe yourself as?

I suppose the answer would be one word (for describing yourself).

I have a dialog with a similar situation:

> John: So you are saying she said decadent about our uncle?!
>
> Victoria: That's *what* she described him. But please, John, don't get angry at
>   her. She didn't mean it, I think.

Is it correct, in my dialog,  to use **what** since she (the person who is talked about) described their uncle by one word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'How' functions as an adverb, and can be used with any sentence that has a verb.  'What' functions as a noun, and can only appear  in a sentence as the subject or object of the verb, or with a preposition.  You can say:

> **What** did you describe?  I described a difficult situation.
>   
>  **How** did you describe **it**?  I described **it** **as** a challenge.

So the original sentence "That's what she described him" is incorrect because the 'what' can neither be the subject nor the object of 'described'.  It could be corrected either as "That's **how** she described him" or using an [attributive ditransitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb#Attributive_ditransitive_verbs) like 'call' as "That's what she called him".